# Consequences of frequent share holder loan and repayment to and from my Ontario Corporation?

Tags: taxes, canada, loans, penalty

Let's say I have an Ontario Corporation in Canada.  My corporate fiscal year is from July 1 to June 30.  I also have a personal line of credit with my personal bank and I owe $50k to the bank.  The bank is charging me 15% interest on the personal line of credit, so that's like about $7.5k interest payment each year.

Let's say I withdraw $50k from my corporation's checking account on July 2, 2023 and put it into my personal line of credit, that way I don't have to pay interest to the bank.

Then on June 25, 2024, just before my corporate fiscal year end, I take $50k out of my personal line of credit and put it back into my corporation's checking account.

Then on July 2, 2024, I take money out of my corporation and put into my personal line of credit again.

Then on June 25, 2025, before the corporate fiscal year end, I return the money to my corporation.

And I repeat this process on the July 2 and June 25 of every year.  This way I hardly pay any interest to the bank for my personal line of credit.

Will the CRA charge me a penalty of some kind for leveraging my corporate cash to avoid paying interest to my personal bank?

I read in a few places that penalties only apply if I don't return the loan within 2 years?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably want to talk to a tax accountant.

In any case, you'll need to pay interest ([5% starting this August](https://thinkaccounting.ca/blog/shareholder-loans/)), which is taxable income to the corporation. So you'll save at most approx. half the interest charge. The risk is that the CRA may decide to combine the loans given the short period between the repayment and the new draw which is clearly a continuation of the loan with no substance other than circumventing the rules. If that happens you'd be assessed tax as if you received dividends due to that 2-year rule you've mentioned.

With all that said, after 2-3 years of that the interest you pay is more than the dividend tax to just take the money and cover the POC, so what are you trying to do here? You'll pay interest to your corp, the corp will pay tax on it, and then you'll pay tax on your own interest payments if/when you get them back as dividends. What for?

Comment: Too bad. A single member LLC in the US could simply classify them as draws and deposits (whatever the opposite is called). You wouldn't even need to do this annually. You could pick whatever timescale you want.

Comment: @user26460 yes, from tax perspective. But from legal liability protection perspective that would pierce your corporate veil. It would probably pose a similar risk in Canada as well, but that's not what the question was about.